# How to properly add new item to ObservableCollection from another thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I get an issue with adding new item to ObservableCollection from another thread:

```
This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.
```

I've googled I need to use code like this to add an item:

```cs
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
{
    Collection.Add(newItem);
});
```

But I have not App class, because code which adds new item is located in external DLL project. I've tried this code:

```cs
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    Collection.Add(newItem)
});
```

but without success. Could you please point me how it can be done?

VS-project which reproduces the issue: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1it_GgwrXm9nZfwJ9xVrBidyEQ4uBkdhy

Comment: Are you able to show the code which calls the external dll for adding to the collection?

Comment: I've created a small VS-solution which reproes the issue: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1it_GgwrXm9nZfwJ9xVrBidyEQ4uBkdhy

Comment: @RyanThomas did you have a chance to see my VS-solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Root cause

I'm adding new item to `ObservableCollection` in method which subscribed to event `Elapsed` of object `System.Timers.Timer`. But the class always create a different thread to run methods which subscribed to the event.

### Solution

Once I've changed it to `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`, the issue has gone, because the timer run "tick"-methods in thread the timer was created or in thread you specified.